# Continue to ask for input until correct answer is given(Python) (Non number values)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a piece of code with that repeats the question until the correct answer is given, with a few different responses for likely answers. This is what I have so far, but after it responds to the input given, the program moves on. I can't figure out how to do this with a while loop since it ends with a specific answer and not with else.

```
answer = input("What is your favorite eldest daughter's name?   ").lower()

if answer == "a" or answer == "al":
    print("Of course, we all knew that")
elif answer == "c" or answer == "chris":
    print("""Oh she must be standing right there.
But that\'s not it, try again.""")

elif answer == "e" or answer == "ed":
    print("Not even the right gender. Try again.")
elif answer == "n" or answer == "nic":
    print("Only biological children please.")

else:
    print("I'm sorry. Only children. Were you thinking of the dogs?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` is what you want. Use it like so:

```
while 1:

    answer = input("What is your favorite eldest daughter's name?   ").lower()

    if answer == "a" or answer == "al": #assuming this is the right answer
        print("Of course, we all knew that")
        break
    elif answer == "c" or answer == "chris":
        print("""Oh she must be standing right there.
    But that\'s not it, try again.""")

    elif answer == "e" or answer == "ed":
        print("Not even the right gender. Try again.")
    elif answer == "n" or answer == "nic":
        print("Only biological children please.")

    else:
        print("I'm sorry. Only children. Were you thinking of the dogs?")
```

Comment: Just what I needed! I didn't know you could do a break on anything besides an else statement, learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to keep repeating the question until the answer is considered to be acceptable by the program.

#### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -B

answers = ['alice', 'chris', 'bob']
answer  = None
while answer not in answers:
    answer = input('Enter your answer: ')

print('Your answer was: {}'.format(answer))
```

Basically the code here has a list of acceptable `answers` and it initializes the user's `answer` to `None`. Then it enters a `while` loop that keeps repeating itself until the user's `answer` is found within the list of acceptable `answers`.

#### Output

```
➜  ~  ./script.py
Enter your answer: alice
Your answer was: alice
➜  ~  ./script.py
Enter your answer: no
Enter your answer: no
Enter your answer: yes
Enter your answer: bob
Your answer was: bob
```

#### Improving the Code

You can now adapt the code to use the messages of your choice. Note, too, that if you want to provide a different response for any of the acceptable entries, you could use a dictionary and update the code slightly.

For example, you could have something like this:

```
answers = {
    'bob': 'This was the best choice',
    'alice': 'Everyone picks the hot gal',
    # ... and so on
}
```

Then you'd keep iterating just like before by checking the *keys* of the `answers` dictionary (e.g. `while answer not in answers.keys():`).

When the loop exits with an acceptable `answer`, you'd simply

```
print(answers[answer])
```

If `answers == 'alice'`, then the program would print `Everyone picks the hot gal`.

It would significantly simplify your code and make it easier for you to understand and work with :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `while` loop, and the `break` statement:

```
while True:
    # . . .
    if correct_answer:
        break
```